# Ubuntu 16.04 and Synced folder

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a VirtualBox machine that runs ubuntu 16.04 lts. it is a desktop ubuntu and i use it for my web application developments. I want to have a folder in my host OS (windows 10) and put my project files in it so it should automatically move to /var/www directory of my ubuntu VM. I searched a lot but there is something named Synced folders in vagrant that looks like it. but problem is i cant run vagrant on a existing VM that manually created by myself. vagrant will make its own VM from a Base Box. I dont know much about it but Here is My main Question:

Is it possible to use vagrant to have a synced folder on ubunto 16.04 VM **created by myself not vagrant** as dev environment and send files to it from a 
windows folder?

If it is not possible what is my best solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this line config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", create: true 
below you config.vm.box variable and the folder where is located Vagrant file will be mapped with /var/www/ directory of your Ubuntu OS. Don't forget to run vagrant reload.